# Growth rate of integral

Tags: integration, asymptotics

My apologies, I have no idea how to make the title more specific without putting the whole question in there. On p. 60 of Montgomery and Vaughan they state
\begin{equation}
2\int_e ^x \frac{1 + \log \log x - \log \log u}{(\log u)^2}du + O(\log \log x) \ll \frac{x}{(\log x)^2}
\end{equation}
but, for the life of me, I cannot figure out how.

Comment: The integral looks like $-\infty$ to me.

Comment: Let $c = 1 + \log\log x$.  Then we have: $\int_{e}^{\infty} \frac{c - \log \log u}{(\log u)^2}du = \int_{z=1}^{\infty}\frac{(c-\log(z))e^z}{z^2}dz$, using change of variable $z=\log(u)$, $dz = du/u = du/e^z$.

Comment: So eventually $(c-\log(z)) < -1$ for all $z > z^*$, and since $e^z/z^2\rightarrow\infty$, we get an integral of $-\infty$.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I got the limits on the integral wrong. Corrected now.

Comment: Oh.  I don't know.  You might consider a L'Hopital type argument using the Liebniz rule. ...seems messy tho.  Gotta go.